# Find value in a table by two criteria (x,y)

Tags: excel, vba

I was asked how to find the value corresponding with two criteria ino one table. Table sample:

[image]

Here is my answer which for `=findval(3200,100)` returns `4,6`:

```
Function findval(x As String, y As String)

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim x_rgn As Range
Dim y_rgn As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

Set x_rgn = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, LastCol))
Set y_rgn = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1))

With x_rgn
    Set val_x = .Find(What:=x, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
    val_x = val_x.Address
    val_x = Range(val_x).Column
End With
With y_rgn
    Set val_y = .Find(What:=y, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
    val_y = val_y.Address
    val_y = Range(val_y).Row
End With
findval = Cells(val_y, val_x).Value
End Function
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Okay. Do you have a question?  If you just want someone to review the code, it's better to post that [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi Bruce, yes sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `3200` in I2 and `100` in J2, rather shorter:

```
=INDEX(A1:G8,MATCH(J2,A:A,0),MATCH(I2,1:1,0))
```

Comment: Nice call, I was about to suggest the same.

Comment: right, I'm used to write every UDF, oblivious to standards function ;-)